# We couldn't access your bot. Make sure you've added "teamsappstudio@microsoft.com" as an admin and try again

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have my bot registered in dev.botframework.com. It is published, up and running well. I'm trying to integrate it on Microsoft Teams. For that, I need to create a manifest, which I'm doing using App Studio. When I arrive to the part of configuring the the bot endpoint on App Studio, App Studio says that I need to add teamsappstudio@microsoft.com to my bot, admin textbox in order for it to find my bot. Here's what it says that I should do:

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

So, I added teamsappstudio@microsoft.com to my bot as an admin as AppStudio says that I should do, but when I click "Setup" in the last part, it shows me the error: "We couldn't access your bot. Make sure you've added "teamsappstudio@microsoft.com" as an admin and try again".

I don't know what else to do!!

Help me with this one guys.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The of Teams App Studio that's live now has a bug - sometimes the email address we extract from your authentication token has uppercase characters. We assumed they were all lowercase but it's likely yours are not. We are changing the logic to ignore case so in a week or two it should work properly.

Sorry for the confusion and hassle.

Comment: Hi Bill. Can you explain further what do you mean with "the email address we extract from your authentication token"? I don't remember writing my email address with uppercase anywhere.

Comment: So, Bill, any other thoughts about why this happen? Do you know where I can find my email to check if it has some uppercase letter?

Comment: This is getting really frustrating.

Comment: Could you please setup your bot endpoint directly in bot framework site till the fix is rolled out? This issue should not block you from creating app manifest in App Studio.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT, I'm folowing these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio in MSFT documentation. It says that I must use App Studio to create the schema file. How setting up "bot endpoint directly in bot framework" is a workaround for this? I don't understand. More help will be appreciated. We are stuck with this.